# Django 4 seems to be caching my query. How can I turn it off?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

### The Issue

When I am updating a property (House) on the website. 
Say for example, I update the `State` to **Illinois** -- the value does not show up in:

```
all_properties = models.Property.objects.all()
```

Even adding a new property (house) does not show up in the `all_properties` value when the `UpdateView` reloads.

It only shows up if I kill the Django server and restart it.

What can I do so that I have updated data show up on every load of the `UpdateView`?

### Some context

I have a model with 20+ attributes. 
This is for a property-listing site (like Airbnb). So there are things like size, bedrooms, city, state, etc.

There needs to be an auto-complete functionality on the textboxes when I am editing these properties.

So for example, `State` is a text field in my form. When I am adding a 2nd house to my website, the `State` textbox should suggest values from the previous houses that I have in my system.

*(Basically when I type C, it should show California if I have any houses with California already in the DB)*

### UpdateView

I am using an Update View to show my Property-Edit (House-Edit) page. 
I need to pass in all these `auto-complete fields` inside this Update View so that I can add them to my text boxes.

The code looks like this:

```
class PropertyUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'property'
    model = models.Property
    form_class = forms.PropertyForm
    template_name = 'desertland/admin/property_update.html'

    extra_context = get_autocomplete_fields()

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'The property was updated successfully.')
        return reverse('property_update', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})
```

The extra_content is where I am passing my autocomplete fields.
The get_autocomplete_fields() method is like so:

```
def get_autocomplete_fields():
    ac_keys = ['state', 'city', 'county', 'zip_code', 'zoning', 'power', 'water_district', 'water', 'access', 'vetting']
    autocomplete_data = {}
    temp_list = {}

    all_properties = models.Property.objects.all()

    # Creating empty dictionaries for the autocomplete fields
    for key in ac_keys:
        temp_list[key] = []
        autocomplete_data[key] = []

    for property in all_properties:
        for key in ac_keys:
            # Creating a key if it does not exist
            if autocomplete_data.get(key) is None:
                autocomplete_data[key] = []

            val = getattr(property, key)

            # Creating an array of distinct values from the property
            if val and val not in temp_list[key]:
                temp_list[key].append(val)
                autocomplete_data[key].append({'value': val, 'label': val})

    return {'autocomplete_data': autocomplete_data}
```

This function works correctly and generates the Dictionary correctly.

**My DB Model looks like this:**

```
class Property(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    ... more attributes ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Property, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("property_update", kwargs={'id': self.pk})
```

**Some further debugging since I posted this question:**

1. The value is updated in the DB immediately.
2. The updated values are shown if I access them via the `ListView` or the `UpdateView`. (i.e. it shows up in the input fields or my table).
3. It is only reflected via the `models.Property.objects.all()` if I restart the Django server.
4. If I create a new object, the count stays the same inside of the `models.Property.objects.all()` method. (i.e. even new objects are not reflected even though they are persisted in the DB).
5. There is no caching framework active.
6. `TIMEOUT=0` in my settings.py has no effect.

Comment: Look at the original db, do you have any cache table present which you created through `python manage.py createcachetable`?

Comment: @SunderamDubey No cache tables created. This is a very basic CRUD application.

Comment: So, maybe you have set settings of cache in settings.py and default is `None` that means cache will not expire, infinite caching. Refer [`TIMEOUT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#timeout)

Comment: @SunderamDubey Thanks Sunderam for trying to help me with this. I checked and did not not a TIMEOUT value in the settings. Adding TIMEOUT=0 also did not solve it for me unfortunately.

Even creating new objects from within the `CreateView` does not update the count via the `models.Property.objects.all()` method -- even though the `UpdateView` will show properties of the newly created object.

It is very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't show up, because you populate them when class is initialized.

```
class PropertyUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'property'
    model = models.Property
    form_class = forms.PropertyForm
    template_name = 'desertland/admin/property_update.html'

    # Here is the issue. extra_context is a static variable and 
    # get_autocomplete_fields() is called when class is initialized,
    # which in your case means when you start the server.
    extra_context = get_autocomplete_fields()
```

You have to move this extra context to get_context_data() method.

```
class PropertyUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'property'
    model = models.Property
    form_class = forms.PropertyForm
    template_name = 'desertland/admin/property_update.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['autocomplete_properties'] = get_autocomplete_fields()
        return context

    extra_context = get_autocomplete_fields()
```

Here is documentation on [adding extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).